# Efficient subsetting and sampling in R

Tags: r, performance, subset

Below is a snippet of R code from a simulation that I have been developing.

```
hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), 
                ind.index, 
                sample(i, size = 1, replace = TRUE)]
```

`ind.index` in the above snippet consists of a single call to `sample(...)`

I profiled my simulation in RStudio and this line is indeed the bottleneck in terms of both runtime and memory (~30000 ms runtime and ~7000 MB).

Is there a more efficient way of expressing the below snippet so that it will be faster?

Before moving fully into Rcpp, I would like to fully exhaust my base R/package options.

One option is perhaps the plyr/dplyr packages (dplyr inherently depends on Rcpp). Because `pop` is an array, so in order to use dplyr, conversion to a data frame is needed. I can then replace `sample(...)` with `sample_n(...)` from `dplyr`.

The goal is to eventually write a package, so calling `.Internal(sample(...))`, though likely faster, is not allowed for CRAN submission.

Below is the full code:

```
## Set up container(s) to hold the identity of each individual from each permutation ##

num.specs <- ceiling(N / K)

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, num.specs), K))

## Create an ID for each haplotype ##

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

## Assign individuals (N) to each subpopulation (K) ##

specs <- 1:num.specs

## Generate permutations, assume each permutation has N individuals, and sample those individuals' haplotypes from the probabilities ##

for (j in 1:perms) {
    for (i in 1:K) {
            pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = num.specs, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
        }
}

## Make a matrix to hold individuals from each permutation ##

HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, num.specs), K))

## Perform haplotype accumulation ##

for (k in specs) {
    for (j in 1:perms) {
        for (i in 1:K) {
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE) # which individuals are sampled
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(i, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] # extract those individuals from a permutation
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot)) # how many haplotypes recovered a given sampling intensity (k) from each permutation (j)
        }
    }
}
```

#### To run:

```
K <- 1 # number of subpopulations
N <- 100 # number of individuals
Hstar <- 10 # number of haplotypes
probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) # haplotype frequency distribution 
perms <- 10000 # number of permutations
```

This is a small example, which is quite fast. However, the power of my simulation comes with investigating larger input parameter values, but this results in considerably slower code.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated and warmly welcomed.

Comment: the above code snippet is part of a nested for loop. i is an index that refers to subarrays that are in the 'pop' variable. All subarrays have equal (same) dimensions

Comment: Is there a way I can have a single call to sample(...) inside my code snippet instead of multiple calls? This will probably speed things up a little.

Comment: I just posted the full code as requested. This should be more clear now. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: To answer your question... yes the pop data is contained in a 3-dimensional array with dimensions c(c(perms, num.specs), K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
K <- 1 # number of subpopulations
N <- 100 # number of individuals
Hstar <- 10 # number of haplotypes
probs <- 1/Hstar # haplotype frequency distribution 
perms <- 10000    
num.specs <- ceiling(N / K)    

## Create an ID for each haplotype ##
haps <- seq_len(Hstar)

## Generate permutations, assume each permutation has N individuals, and sample those individuals' haplotypes from the probabilities ##
sim_fun <- function()
{
  return(sample( x = haps, 
                 size = num.specs, 
                 replace = TRUE, 
                 prob = rep(0.1, Hstar)))
}

set.seed(2L)
pop <- array(dim = c(num.specs, perms, K))
for (i in 1:K) {
  pop[, , i] <- replicate(perms, sim_fun())
}
```

The nested for loop is reduced by one level which will improve efficiency dramatically, because the outer loop represents number of sub-populations, which most likely will be a small number when compared to number of individuals and number of permutations. You can't avoid sampling at three occasions, because of three different dimensions with varying length in them.

```
# n_ind = number of individuals
# n_perm = number of permutations
# n_subpop = number of subpopulations
# prob = sampling probability
# FUN = summary statistics function

# summary statistics
extract_stats <- function(n_ind, n_perm, n_subpop, prob, FUN, ... )
{

  ijk <- dim(pop)
  sapply( seq_len(n_subpop), function( y ){
    pop_dat <- pop[sample( x = seq_len(ijk[1]), size = n_ind, replace = TRUE, prob = rep( prob, ijk[1] ) ),
                   sample( x = seq_len(ijk[2]), size = n_perm, replace = TRUE, prob = rep( prob, ijk[2] ) ),
                   sample( x = seq_len(ijk[3]), size = y, replace = TRUE, prob = rep( prob, ijk[3] ) )]
    ifelse( test = is.matrix(pop_dat), 
            yes = apply( pop_dat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = FUN ),
            no = do.call(FUN, c( list(pop_dat), ...) ))
  })
}

# median of haplotype id
replicate(10, extract_stats( n_ind = 100, n_perm = 2, n_subpop = 2, prob = 0.1, FUN = median))
# minimum of haplotype id
replicate(10, extract_stats( 100, 2, 2, 0.1, min))
# maximum of haplotype id
replicate(10, extract_stats( 100, 2, 2, 0.1, max))
# histogram of haplotype id distribution
replicate(1, extract_stats( n_ind = 100, n_perm = 1, n_subpop = 1, prob = 0.1, FUN = hist, xlab = "haplotype_id", main = "title"))
```

Comment: probability can't be greater than 1. In your question, you have 0.1 and 10.

Comment: so I used only 0.1. If you want haplotype id for different probability distribution, create one more dimension that holds this data. For example `pop <- array(dim = c(num.specs, perms, K, 2))`

Comment: use `set.seed(number)` to get reproducible results. Otherwise you will get different results when you run `sample()` multiple times without setting the pseudo random number generator

Comment: Note: I switched number of rows and columns, so your code following this will have to take this into account. Now rows indicate number of individuals. In your question, columns indicated number of individuals

Comment: what are you trying to do with the code in : Perform haplotype accumulation?

Comment: I think this code: `apply(pop, 2, table)` will answer your task: how many haplotypes recovered a given sampling intensity (k) from each permutation (j) . I am guessing and do not know what you mean by haplotype accumulation

Comment: set `perms <- 10` for testing purpose. It will make life easy. You can change it to larger number later

Comment: I haven't included the code here, but I use results from hap.plot to create some graphs and output some simple statistics.

Comment: I will try out your solution, assuming its for the nested for loop posted in my question. Thank you!

Comment: are you trying to find the frequency of each haplotype in a given permutation of 100 individuals?

Comment: my guess is that you can completely avoid the second nested for loop. If you tell what you are trying to do with the simulated haplotype id for each subpopulation, it will help me to suggest on the nested for loop.

Comment: Very close. I am trying to see if I can recover all haplotypes from sampling 100 individuals

Comment: From my answer you have those the haplotypes for 100 individuals, so you don't need the second nested for loop

Comment: If you want to see distribution of haplotypes in each permutation, try this `apply(pop, 2, table)`

Comment: The nested for loop samples 1 permutation (row) from one of the K subpopulations at random.

Comment: yes, if you have two subpopulation, then the third dimension will be 2. See my comments above. Based on your question, 100 will be divided into two as 50 in each subpopulation

Comment: But in the end I am just looking for speed in my code/algorithm

Comment: change `K <- 2` and see it for yourself

Comment: in my answer, I avoided the first nested for loop, which will improve efficiency dramatically. My guess is that you don't need second nested for loop. You can do summary statistics and histogram will the data you got in `pop`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try it out!

Comment: I used art of your solution and am now looking to use Rcpp for the rest. I will accept the answer and upvote.